# Ifttt not filling fields

Tags: ifttt

I have a Bosch Easycontrol thermostat and it's supposed to be compatible with ifttt.

What happens though is that I click on the integration and no matter which action I choose, the field "which room" is stuck in "Loading..." and I cannot complete any action. I tried re-connecting the service and the standard ways but nothing works.

I'd like to know how to fix it or at least if it's an ifttt issue or a Bosch issue.

Comment: have you contacted Bosch?

Comment: @jsotola As I said, I don't know if it's an issue on the side of Bosch or ifttt. But other than that I see no technical support contact for this kind of issue on the bosch website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that I forgot the basic step of actually connecting the device to IFTTT via the "external service" menu in the smartphone app.

What I did was open the app on the phone, click "settings", then "external services", then "Easycontrol pairing page".

That will require the serial number, access code and password.

The first two are visible in the app under "Info" then "About", while the password is the one set in the app, NOT the one for the Bosch identity.